# What does "Latest Restore Time" says in AWS RDS(Mysql) instances page

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have two RDS MySQL instances and when I look at the instances page, I have seen a field named "Latest Restore Time" and the value for it is some time stamp in IST time zone.

I would like to know what it actually mean. Being the individual server:

- What is the need for this to be Restored?
- Where it gets restored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the RDS Console tooltip, the `Latest Restore Time` defines `The latest time to which a database can be restored with point-in-time restore.` and not the last time the database was restored.

The database can be restored from Amazon RDS Automated Backup tool that can be configured in the Amazon RDS `Modify DB Instance` page. The default window backup is 7 days, every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> You can restore to any point in time during your backup retention period. To determine the latest restorable time for a DB instance, use the AWS CLI describe-db-instances command and look at the value returned in the LatestRestorableTime field for the DB instance. **The latest restorable time for a DB instance is typically within 5 minutes of the current time.**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html